# Tube Deformation Animation with Pill Passing Through

Tags: animation, physics, collision

I'm making a medical video featuring a robotic pill passing through the human digestive tract. The animation features the pill sliding down a cross-section of the esophagus and small intestine. I'm wondering if anyone has an idea of how I would create the deformation effect of the pill pressing against the wall of the tube. For example, the pill is larger than the diameter of the tube, when when the tube is relaxed, but when the pill passes through, the tube stretches to fit the pill as it slides through the tube. I'm trying to find a more procedural way of going about this to avoid shape-keying the whole thing. Any ideas?

Comment: You can search for Dynamic Paint. Pill as a Brush, Tube as a Canvas with displace effect. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGujs4z2C6E

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll give it a shot

Comment: You can also create your Answer here, so others can learn from you. Thank you keep this site useful :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked up the Dynamic Paint approach that @vklidu cited and it worked very well. Blender 2.8+ changed a few things, which actually made this task easier. There's a displacement option directly in the canvas settings for the object, and when everything's set up right, it works great, and procedurally, is flawless.

Comment: Someone downvote probably for very low info, Usually step by step is expected with screens illustrates process. Thank you keep this site useful.